# Raspberry Pi VPN Server w/o Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, vpn, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to setup my raspberry pi as a temporary VPN for while I am traveling. Problem is I don't have access to the home router, so I can't set up port forwarding. So I researched a bit and these are the methods I have found.

#### 1. [remote.it](https://remote.it/) and other [similar services](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/)

I'm not entirely sure how this service works, but it seems to act like a proxy, forwarding traffic to the Raspi. However, I'm worried that I will be restricted by the bandwidth of the remote.it servers, eg when I am trying to stream video. It does seem like remote.it has a way to set up a direct connection using a [client script](https://github.com/remoteit/misc_bins_and_scripts/tree/master/ssh_client) but it doesn't really explain how it works, and I don't think I would be able to use that on my phone.

#### 2. Reverse SSH Tunneling

This is the method I see talked about the most. However, from the explanations I've read online, I still can't tell if the proxy server is used for all traffic, or just for establishing the initial connection. If I use a 3rd party service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), would I be limited to the bandwidth of their servers?

#### 3. UPnP

This seems like the simplest method, and doesn't require any additional servers. However, it doesn't seem to be mentioned much so I'm wondering if there are some glaring issues I am overlooking.

Overall, I am just looking for a comparison between limitations and security of the three methods (or any other methods you can suggest). Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**1:**
Remote.it and co. are services that work by playing [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) and forward your commands. Now I don't say they *are* capturing everything you do but they very well *could*, although when you exchange your certificates through a secure channel before, you should be good. Whether they work with VPN I don't know, they seem to be [rather constrained](https://remot3it.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021802791-Does-remote-it-work-with-ftp-) when wanting to use multiple ports. I wouldn't use them to run all my traffic through, even when encrypted; and they might not like it either.

**2:** This seems to be your best bet. If you don't have a static IP I recommend using [DuckDNS](http://duckdns.org) for that. Setting up a reverse SSH-Tunnel is also [really easy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/80058/88271)

**3:** [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upnp#Overview) is a protocol to enable plug and play networking. It opens ports by sending requests to the router to do so. If it is available to you, you could open all the ports you need [like this](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/ssb22/setup/upnp.html). But beware, it can be [quite](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38661/146549) [insecure](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/answer/UPnP-vulnerability-How-is-the-UPnP-protocol-being-misused) to have active.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. It does seem like reverse say tunneling is the most recommended, but my biggest worry is that it seems to also require some sort of MitM. What exactly is the MitM server used for? Is it persistently rerouting all traffic, or is it only used to establish a connection?

Comment: Oh and I should clarify that since I will be traveling around, my client IP will be constantly changing, so I can't just have my raspi directly connect to my client like in the reverse ssh example you provided. In other words, both my server and client don't have port forwarding capabilities

Comment: The service needs to play MitM to set up the connection. It is the thing your client and server both know(after they resolve the URL to get an IP). The service can then establish a connection between the two parties, depending on implementation this means you have to trust the service with quite a lot of information about your traffic and you(IP). DuckDNS _already solves_ the problem you have with the changing IP. Just have your client register there and yours server shall try to establish a connection with it every minute or so.

Comment: @jaaq - Will all traffic go through MitM? I would like to set up something like that. But I would like to be able send a lot of data. And VM on some hosting service with this amount of bandwidth costs fortune.

Is there a way to initialize connection using MitM but connect 2 devices directly after that?

Comment: @Hooch there isn't any good free offers I am aware of besides [ProtonVPN](https://protonvpn.com/)